# API security: Real date of the user

Tags: api, date, security, xmlhttprequest

### Situation:

I'm creating inner API for my website (Node.js + Express). But I completely don't know how to secure it.

I have payments in my application, and I need to know when user makes it. I use XHR requests for transferring data between server and frontend.

### Questions:

1. Is it secure to transfer user's time to a server (can I trust this information?). If no, how can I get it securely? I thought about transferring user's location, and then with help of mement.js get his time, but it's also not secure if a hacker can replace it with his data.
2. Can hacker make XHR request from developer's console to my server? If yes, how can I get his real time?

I'll be happy if you answer at least some of my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest not writing the code yourself if you are not confident enough about it. Storing payment details is a big responsibility, and can get you in legal trouble if anything gets compromised. I would suggest using services like Paypal to handle the payment.

That said, I am going to answer your question:

1. You cannot trust **ANY** information you receive from the user. The time and location can be spoofed/altered very easily.
2. Yes, it is possible to make (modify) a request from the console (maybe some add-ons and technical knowledge will be required, but it is doable). It is not possible to know the real time of the user. It is only possible to know the session timeout of the server, and estimate the time of the user, relative to the time of the server, based on that. It is also possible to know the IP of the user and estimate the time-zone, but using a VPN or Tor, it is trivial for a user to alter it.

**EDIT:** Using Paypal would increase the security, compared to writing it yourself. Here is the API reference: https://developer.paypal.com/

**EDIT 2:** Here is a brief explanation of why you should **never** trust user input: https://www.enisa.europa.eu/publications/info-notes/the-dangers-of-trusting-user-input